# Understanding Facebook Graph API identifiers

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

While I do realize that the ids for graph api objects are not documented, I'm seeing some oddities which I'd like to understand.

I have an authorized app that polls a page's feed for new comments and it looks like I'm getting different ids for the same post.
On first run I get a post with the id of:

`1470990656482896_1553567768225184`

Which is the id of the page and post joined by an underscore.
The second poll which ran a few minutes later, I received the same post with a different id:

`100008124617959_1553567768225184`

Which is the user id of the poster and post joined by an underscore.

While I'd like to understand the inconsistency, the real problem is trying to access the post via the second identifier returns an `Unsupported get request` with the code of `100`

The post is public and is accessible via both
`https://www.facebook.com/100008124617959/posts/1553567768225184`

and

`https://www.facebook.com/1470990656482896/posts/1553567768225184`

Comment: File a bug. `100008124617959_1553567768225184` isn't a valid Facebook API object. Yes https://www.facebook.com/100008124617959/posts/1553567768225184 exists but in the API it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like an oauth problem. While the post is public, to access it via the graph API you have to use an access token.

If you use the access token for Hans Gotwo then you should be able to access the post with the id of `100008124617959_1553567768225184`

Comment: Thanks. Perhaps I should have mentioned that all access to the Graph API is done with access tokens. I cannot access the post via Graph api explorer for `100008124617959_1553567768225184` even when logged in as the original poster with a new access token

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's a bug. thanks @phwd
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/721538487964698/